# Method to make certain directories ignore htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What methods are there to make certain directories in the root folder ignore `htaccess` rules (i.e don't perform any htaccess processing in these folders), other than putting a `.htaccess` file with `RewriteEngine Off` in each of these folders?

Can the rule of `RewriteEngine Off` be applied to all these folders in one go somewhere?

I'd like to exclude folders images, mod, user, signup from being processed by the main `.htaccess` file that's in the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore certain directories from rewrite rules use a rule like this just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(dir1|dir2|dir3)(/.*)?$ - [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hmm... That goes in the `.htaccess` file itself, which is pretty messy. The `httpd.conf` file wont handle this?

Comment: Yes `httpd.conf` is also fine but you need to restart Apache after this change and remember to use latest updated rule in `httpd.conf`

Comment: Thanks. BTW, which folders does a `.htaccess` file affect? For Ex: If i place a `.htaccess` file with `RewriteEngine Off` in `/main`, and `main` has `Sub1`, `Sub2`, will it affect only the files in `main` or even folders `Sub1` and `Sub2`?

Comment: It will affect `/main` and all the the directories underneath so `/main/sub1` and `/main/sub2` also.